# What is the Mother of Dragons hat for?

Tags: support

SPOILER ALERT (for *Game of Thrones*):

For some reason I got this hat that looks like Daenerys' hair (from GoT), my wild guess is since I got the hat due to a posting about mass bombing, then the Mother of Dragons' temper-tantrum in King's Landing, as a sort of dragon-napalm air raid, is the reference for the sake of the hat...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not yet got around to watching GoT, but the requirements for the Mother of Dragons hat are listed in an [answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304919/437864) on Meta:SE.

From that answer:

> requirements for the hat were:
>
> - Visit a site where you have *never* posted a question or answer before (even if it's been deleted).
> - Post a new question or answer *during* Winter Bash.
> - Get its score to at least 3.
> - Wait until the post is 3 days old.
> - The post cannot be deleted or community wiki, and if it's a question, it cannot be closed.